# Hacer un ArrayList de checkbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He conseguido poner un array de checkbox en el Form1.Designer.cs
tal que así:

```
this.caja = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox[] {checkBox1 , checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5, checkBox6,
         checkBox7 ,checkBox8 ,checkBox9 ,checkBox10 ,checkBox11 ,checkBox12 ,checkBox13 ,checkBox14 ,checkBox15 ,checkBox16};
```

Quería saber si se puede poner con ArrayList:
Lo pongo así y me da error:

```
this.caja = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox ArrayList caja = new ArrayList() { };
```

Comment: Que es `this.caja`? Un array de `CheckBox`?

Comment: Si esto (declarado tambien en Form1.Designer.cs): public.System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox[] caja;

Comment: Y porqué lo pones en el designer? que sentido tiene? echa un vistazo a mi respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varias cosas. Lo primero, no se debe tocar el `Designer.cs`, ya que es autogenerado y puede darte problemas, puedes hacer lo mismo en el código de tu formulario.

Segundo, no utilices `ArrayList`,es una clase que es obsoleta y que ha sido sustituida por la clase genérica `List`.

En el caso que expones, utilizando `List` tu código sería el siguiente:

```
List<CheckBox> listaCb = new List<CheckBox>() { checkBox1 , checkBox2... };
```

Por otro lado, si `this.caja` es de tipo `CheckBox[]`, tambien debes modificar su definición para que sea `List<CheckBox>`:

```
List<CheckBox> caja;
```